# Hosting a Multitiered Application On Arvixe

Tags: wcf

Pls I have a multi tiered application which includes the service layer, presentation layer, data access layer.  Please does anyone have a guideline on how to host this. ordinary web publishing does not seem to work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ticket number for your issue? If not, please create one, Arvixe's Support team would be able to assist you with the deployment of your Multitiered Application by trying to come up with a solution. If you e-mail QA[@]Arvixe.com they will be sure to get you some assistance